# print or iterate over the vertices with vertex_descriptor boost graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph, vertex, descriptor

Building a boost graph where edges area added (below) and v1 is defined as

```
gm->create_edge(v1,v2,1); 
boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor v1 = gm-> create_vertex("one",1,1);
```

How do print or enumerate the vertices using?:

```
boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vd;
```

This allows me to print vertex id:

```
Graph::vertex_iterator v, vend, vnext; 
for (boost::tie(v, vend) = vertices(gm->g); v != vend; ++v)
    std::cout << gm->g[*v].id << ", "  << gm->g[*v].color << ", ";
```

I have a function for the degree of the node, it takes a vertex descriptor, so, how do I pass that?

```
gm->degree( takes vertex_descriptor )?
```

This [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540115/boost-graph-getting-adjacent-vertices) is close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vertices(g)` returns an iterator pair. Indirecting the iterator gives the descriptor. In your own example `v` is `vertex_iterator` so `*v` is `vertex_descriptor`.

Lets use Boost's `degree` function - which also takes a descriptor:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0dc9e9a3efdb42d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

namespace MyProgram {
    using namespace boost;
    struct VertexProps { int id; default_color_type color; };

    using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, VertexProps>;

    Graph make_sample_graph();
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using MyProgram::Graph;
    Graph g = MyProgram::make_sample_graph();

    Graph::vertex_iterator v, vend;
    for (boost::tie(v, vend) = vertices(g); v != vend; ++v) {
        std::cout << "Vertex descriptor #" << *v 
             << " degree:" << degree(*v, g)
             << " id:"     << g[*v].id
             << " color:"  << g[*v].color
             << "\n";
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to use ranged-for though:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/717ee87d85cd968b)</kbd>**

```
for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
    std::cout << "Vertex descriptor #" << vd 
         << " degree:" << degree(vd, g)
         << " id:"     << g[vd].id
         << " color:"  << g[vd].color
         << "\n";
}
```

For completeness with `make_sample_graph()`:

```
namespace MyProgram {
    Graph make_sample_graph() {
        Graph g(10);
        for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
            g[vd] = { int(vd)*100, {} };

        add_edge(1,2,g);
        add_edge(2,3,g);
        add_edge(4,5,g);
        add_edge(4,6,g);
        add_edge(6,7,g);

        return g;
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Vertex descriptor #0 degree:0 id:0 color:0
Vertex descriptor #1 degree:1 id:100 color:0
Vertex descriptor #2 degree:2 id:200 color:0
Vertex descriptor #3 degree:1 id:300 color:0
Vertex descriptor #4 degree:2 id:400 color:0
Vertex descriptor #5 degree:1 id:500 color:0
Vertex descriptor #6 degree:2 id:600 color:0
Vertex descriptor #7 degree:1 id:700 color:0
Vertex descriptor #8 degree:0 id:800 color:0
Vertex descriptor #9 degree:0 id:900 color:0
```